# why does sorting in setSomething function of useState hook does not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have 2 components. One is `App` component and other one is `NumbersList` component.
The `NumbersList` is a child component of the `App` component.
The `App` component receives a list of numbers called lst as a prop.
The `App` component has 2 buttons sort Ascending and sort Descending and they try to do what the name implies.

The app component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import NumbersList from './NumbersList';

export default function App({ lst }) {
  const [sortedLst, setSortedLst] = useState(lst);
  function sortAscHandler() {
    setSortedLst((prev) => prev.sort((a, b) => a - b));
  }
  function sortDescHandler() {
    setSortedLst((prev) => prev.sort((a, b) => b - a));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={sortAscHandler}>Sort Ascending</button>
      <button onClick={sortDescHandler}>Sort Descending</button>
      <NumbersList lst={sortedLst} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The NumbersList component:

```js
import React from 'react';

const NumbersList = ({ lst }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {lst.map((num) => (
        <li>{num}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default NumbersList;
```

The main index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
const lst = [4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 100, 9, 8];

ReactDOM.render(<App lst={lst} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The problem is the the when the buttons are clicked, the sortedLst is not updated in the view.

stackblitz-link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jyqeuy?file=src%2Findex.js

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort` is an in-place sort. In other words, it mutates the array it operates on and doesn't return a new array reference.

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array ***in place*** and
> returns the sorted array.

Make a shallow copy first, *then* sort the **new** array reference.

```
export default function App({ lst }) {
  const [sortedLst, setSortedLst] = useState(lst);
  function sortAscHandler() {
    setSortedLst((prev) => prev.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b));
  }
  function sortDescHandler() {
    setSortedLst((prev) => prev.slice().sort((a, b) => b - a));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={sortAscHandler}>Sort Ascending</button>
      <button onClick={sortDescHandler}>Sort Descending</button>
      <NumbersList lst={sortedLst} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes now it makes sense. 
Since the ```Array.prototype.sort``` is returning an array, I thought it was making a new copy of the array now I understand it does not.
I think you may have been mistaken, we need to make a deep copy first and then sort it. The ```.slice()``` creates a deep copy
Thank You

Comment: @karthiksuryadevara Just a minor point of clarification, `.slice()` only creates a shallow copy, all the array elements are references into the previous array, i.e. copy by reference. Only the array itself is a new reference.

Comment: oh, so if I have objects which are references in the array, they will still point to the old reference. Understood 
Thanks for the clarification, I appreciate it